# How to loop through an object attribute with list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have a list - `list_of_objects = [<obj1>,<obj2>]`. Each object has an attribute `<ob1j>.content`. Each `content` attribute holds a list of dictionaries `[{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value"}]`. How do I use list comprehension to "unpack" these dictionaries into a single list? Example that doesn't work:

```
list_of_dictionaries = [dict for obj in list_of_objects for item in obj.content]
```

Basically I want to turn the below loop that works into a comprehension:

```
for obj in list_of_objects:
    new_list.extend(obj.content)
```

Comment: That doesn't work because you're filling the list with references to `dict`, maybe swap that to `item` so it's the thing from the object's content?

Answer (score -1):

Calling dir on the object gives you back all the attributes of that object, including python special attributes.You can always filter out the special methods by using a list comprehension.

Comment: How is this related? OP wants to get a very specific attribute - `content` - not ***all*** attributes...